# Получить копию страницы Angular

Tags: angular2, angular

Есть задача создать копии SPA страниц автоматически, которые генерируются на Angular. Нужно это чтобы дать яндексу статическкие Html страницы, так как SPA он кушать не хочет, а ручками сохранять странички, как то жестоко.

Какие есть средства в Angular, чтобы получить копию готовой страницы и отправить ее на сервер. Чтобы там обработать ну и сохранить как страницу. Ну как отправить и обработать боле менее понятно, а вот как сказать Angular взять свою готовую страницу в виде html, чтобы впоследствии ее отдать?

Comment: Почитайте про [сервеный рендер](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

Answer (score 0):

Короче забрать код на фронте у меня не получилось, но можно генерировать файлы на серверной стороне. В принципе с этим кое как разберусь.

Но вот с размещением не могу понять, вот для Яндекса например:

Если вы используете режим HTML5 routing mode
То для правильной поисковой индексации в код страницы следует включить мета-тег:

Например, если страница доступна по адресу www.example.com/blog и содержит мета-тег , то робот проиндексирует HTML-версию страницы по адресу www.example.com/blog?_escaped_fragment_= .

Вот из описания, если у меня рендерится страница www.example.com/blog, то яндекс робот обнаружив метатег    будет индексировать страницу www.example.com/blog?_escaped_fragment_=  , отсюда вопрос, где должен лежать снимок blog.html , чтобы он нашелся по адресу www.example.com/blog?_escaped_fragment_=   ?